# SQL update column depending on other values in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table similar to this:

```
Index    Name       Type
--------------------------------
1        'Apple'   'Fruit'
2        'Carrot'  'Vegetable'
3        'Orange'  'Fruit'
3        'Mango'   'Fruit'
4        'Potato'  'Vegetable'
```

and would like to change it to this:

```
Index    Name       Type
--------------------------------
1        'Apple'   'Fruit 1'
2        'Carrot'  'Vegetable 1'
3        'Orange'  'Fruit 2'
3        'Mango'   'Fruit 3'
4        'Potato'  'Vegetable 2'
```

Any chance to do this in a smart update query (*= without cursors*)?

Comment: Is it a requirement not to use Cursors or you don't like them ?

Comment: Does the above table has any primary key defined?

Comment: Actually my headline was wrong, replace "row" with "column". Unfortunately I didn't find a way to edit it. I prefered this answer as it is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `update` with `join` to get [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) within `[type]` group for each row and then concatenate this values with `[type]` using `[index]` as glue column:

```
update t1 set t1.[type] = t1.[type] + ' ' + cast(t2.[rn] as varchar(3))
from [tbl] t1
join ( select [index]
            , row_number() over (partition by [type] order by [index]) as [rn]
       from [tbl]
     ) t2 on t1.[index] = t2.[index]
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fb1b/2)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your table has a Primary Key called ID then you can run the following:

```
update fruits
set Type = newType
from
(
select f.id
       ,f.[index] 
       ,f.Name 
       ,f.[Type] 
       ,Type + ' '+ cast((select COUNT(*) 
                          from fruits 
                          where Type = f.Type 
                          and Fruits.id <= f.id) as varchar(10)) as newType
    from fruits f
) t
where t.id = fruits.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Index ,Name, Type, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Index)AS RowNum
INTO #temp
FROM table_name

UPDATE #temp
SET Type = Type + ' ' + CAST(RowNum AS NVARCHAR(15))

UPDATE table_name
SET Type = t2.Type
FROM table_name t1
JOIN #temp t2 ON t2.Index = t1.Index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that you can update cte:

```
with cte as(select type, row_number() over(partition by type order by index) rn from table)
update cte set type = type + ' ' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
```